# sql left converts char to int?

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I'm trying to compare a table and a report table as a proof of test, with the report table containing a 12 character ID plus their DOB, and the source table only having an ID.

```
select cast(ID as char(12)) as ID into #IDnums
from members
where client='some_client'

select ID
from #IDnums
where ID not in (
     select left(12,rtrim(ltrim(memberID)))
     from report_table
     )
```

memberID is a char(50) field. When I run this I get the error:

> The conversion of the varchar value '74857358238119880131' overflowed an int column.

I have no idea where the varchar or int comes from, or how to fix this.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some non-ANSI SQL there...

Comment: well, you are using `LEFT` wrong, it's supposed to be the string first, and the length later: `left(rtrim(ltrim(memberID)),12)`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `left()` the first argument is the string and the second argument is the length.

Hence, it is interpreting the expression on `memberid` as an integer.  That is where the conversion is failing.  You want:

```
select ID
from #IDnums
where ID not in (select left(rtrim(ltrim(memberID)), 12) from report_table);
```

I consider it a bad habit to use `not in` with a subquery.  The problem is what happens if `memberId` is ever `NULL`.  In that case, `not in` returns no rows at all.  That is why I suggest using `not exists` instead.

It is also not clear to me why you are using a temporary table.  Does this do what you want:

```
select id
from members m
where not exists (select 1
                  from report_table rt
                  where left(rt.memberId, 12) = cast(m.id as varchar(12))
                 );
```

or:

```
select id
from members m
where not exists (select 1
                  from report_table rt
                  where rt.memberId like concat(m.id, '%')
                 );
```